# jQuery .remove() not working when iterating through variable

Tags: jquery

I cannot seem to get my jQuery code working. I am trying to modify a table row collection. Here is my code:

```
//rowCollection: a number of <tr> elements without a parent element (i.e. <tr /> <tr /> <tr />....)
//currentRow: any <tr /> element that is also contained in 'rowCollection'
function removeCurrentRow(rowCollection, currentRow) {
    var filteredRowCollection;
    filteredRowCollection = rowCollection;

    filteredRowCollection.each(function () {
        if($(this).text() == currentRow.text()){
            filteredRowCollection.find($(this)).remove();
        }
    });

    return filteredRowCollection;
}
```

Basically, I am trying to remove the a row from a variable (not actual page html, it should remain visible in browser). But when I output the text of both the original row collection and the filtered one, it's still the same.

```
function highLightRedundantTimes() {
    var rowCollection = $('.ms-listviewtable:first > tbody  > tr');

    rowCollection.each(function () {

    var filteredRowCollection = removeCurrentRow(rowCollection.clone(), $(this));

    console.log("Original: " + rowCollection.text());
    console.log("This: " + $(this).text());
    console.log("Filtered: " + filteredRowCollection.text());
    console.log(" ")
});
}
```

Can anybody help me here?

EDIT:

My rowCollection would look like this:

```
<tr><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td></tr>
<tr><td>value</td><td>value</td><td>value</td><td>value</td></tr>
<tr><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td></tr>
```

In this case, when iterating with the first/third `<tr>` as "currentRow", it would be removed from the "filteredRowCollection" and only the third/first and second `<tr>` would remain, respectively.

Comment: filteredRowCollection.find($(this).text()).remove(); Did you try this ?

Comment: yes. it gives me an error: "Syntax error, unrecognized expression:...."

Comment: jQuery's remove method as documented here https://api.jquery.com/remove/ is "Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM" so it is not for removing elements from a Javascript array

Comment: correct me if I am mistaken but I thought that if I used $('   ') I would automatically use jQuery? I edited my code to make this more clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code, correctly, I believe you are misusing `$this`.

```
filteredRowCollection.each(function () {
    if($(this).text() == currentRow.text()){
        filteredRowCollection.find($(this)).remove();
    }
});
```

Try, something like below.

`$this` , references the current scope, so I would think `$this = filteredRowCollection`.

```
filteredRowCollection.each(function () {
    if($(this).text() == currentRow.text()){
         $(this).find(currentRow.text).remove();
    }
});
```

Also, you are using an Each loop, so the find may not be necessary.

### Update

`$(this)` represents the collection, so by using `$(this).children().remove()` will get you into the collections items and remove the item from the row.

Comment: the output is still the same :(

Comment: do a console.log on currentRow.text, make sure it is the text you are expecting. @LeonidasFett

Comment: I debugged this code. the .remove() part is being executed. but when inspecting "filteredRowCollection.text()" before and after .remove(), it was the same.

Comment: @LeonidasFett what does filteredRowCollection represent? Is it an HTML table, is it a webform grid, etc...

Comment: yes, it is an html table. it's being generated by sharepoint so the html would be barely readable. but I added a simplified version of it in my question.

Comment: @LeonidasFett ughhh the only thing worse than webforms is SharePoint. This is probably causing you problems, since SP generates so much garbage. Are you doing this in a Content Web Part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74288/discussion-between-snowyetis-and-leonidasfett).

Comment: no, it's the html of the AllItems.aspx page. I am trying to highlight rows where a time value overlaps with that of another row.

Comment: @LeonidasFett can you jump in the chat room?

Comment: sorry about that. ok I'm in